# No Background when Rendering an UIView to a PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiview, render

In my iPad app I use the following method to render a `UIView` to a PDF.

```
+ (NSData*)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

This works quite fine. My problem is that everything is rendered correctly (all subviews) but the views background is always white. What do I have to change if I want that the view's background is also rendered correctly?

Comment: maybe set aView.layer.backgroundColor to some value? Not sure, I never did this

Comment: Is the background a color? Or is it an image (JPEG, PNG)?

Comment: The background is already set to a UIColor when entering this method.

Comment: the above works fine. either there is no bg or you need to add a minimal example xcode project

Comment: There is an issue with basic rendering PDFs. Preview and Acrobat renders the PDF just fine, but different apps show the background to be white or in the case of Basecamp, magenta. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

if the view has a valid bg, it is rendered to the pdf:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //bg
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    //make pdf
    NSData *pdf = [ViewController createPDFfromUIView:self.view];
    [pdf writeToFile:@"/Users/dominik/t.pdf" atomically:NO];

}

+ (NSData*)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView
{
        //question source code (see above)
}
@end
```

**so: set a backgroundColor**